# Can a pair of complex numbers be "completely" algebraically independent?

Tags: analysis, field-theory, transcendental-numbers

Two complex numbers $\alpha,\beta$ are called algebraically independent if there is no polynomial $p(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ such that $p(\alpha,\beta)=0$.

For a complex number $x$, let $A(x)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:x \text{ is algebraic over } \mathbb{Q}(z)\}$

Can there exist a pair of complex numbers $x,y$ such that $A(x)\cap A(y)$ is empty? Such a pair would also be algebraically independent.

A necessary condition for it to be empty is that both of them must be transcendental over the rationals. For all $x\in\mathbb{C}$, $x$ is contained in $A(x)$, so $A(x)$ is never empty. If $x$ is algebraic over the rationals, then $A(x)$ would be the whole of $\mathbb{C}$. It follows that if either $x$ or $y$ is algebraic over the rationals, then the intersection would not be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ but not over $\mathbb{Q}$ then $z$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$. Hence your notion of "complete" algebraic independence is the same as the classical https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence
and there are plenty of such pairs $(x,y)$.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I'll edit my main post.

Comment: I think it is unfair. Couldn't you mark my answer as accepted instead?

Comment: You're right, I would have done that as well had I read your comment before realising the following: If $A(x)\cap A(y)$ is **not** empty, where $x$ and $y$ are transcendental over the rationals, then there is a transcendental number $z$ such that $x$ and $y$ are both algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(z)$. Since $x$ is not itself algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, there must be a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ of which $x$ is a root. This means that, by way of the same polynomial, $z$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$.

Comment: ^ this is what you suggested with your answer. But although $z$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ and $y$ over $\mathbb{Q}(z)$, this does not mean that $y$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$, does it? Edit: oh wait it does, haha!

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to show that, for each specific polynomial $p$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ with $t$ indeterminate, the set of pairs $(x,z)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $x$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ via $p$ is nowhere-dense in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Consequently, the set of pairs $(x,z)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $x$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ at all and $z$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ at all is comeager, so by the Baire category theorem nonempty.

A similar argument shows that the set of pairs $(x,z)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ such that neither $x$ nor $z$ is algebraic over the other has full measure (= its complement is null). So in multiple senses, "most" pairs of complex numbers have the property you ask about.

Similarly, for a fixed transcendental $x\in\mathbb{C}$, the set of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $x$ and $z$ are each transcendental over the other is comeager and of full measure.

Comment: Do there exist transcendental complex numbers $x$ and $y$ such that even though $x$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(y)$ and $y$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$, there is a third number $z$ such that both $x$ and $y$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(z)$? In that case, $A(x)\cap A(y)$ (as defined in the main post) would still be non-empty.

Comment: @AnujG.R this cannot happen because if the [transcendence_degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree) (over $\mathbb Q$) of the field $\mathbb Q(x,y)$ is $2$, this field cannot be an algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q(z)$.